# Python file error while running the file, no helpful feedback from the terminal as well. Any idea what this means?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, traceback

The code is absolutely correct, here is the link to the repository from where I cloned it: https://github.com/nft-fun/generate-bitbirds.

I did not use the in-built vs code one-it was having some other issues, used other but already activated using **conda init** beforehand

The only prerequisite was to install the *dependencies* and so I did.
After doing that I activated the *base* **conda env** then run the py script, and this is what it shows.

```
C:\Users\Zee\Documents\NFT_Tests\generate-bitbirds (main -> origin)
(base) λ python bitbird_generation_script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bitbird_generation_script.py", line 244, in <module>
   new_image.save(imgname)
File "C:\Users\Zee\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2232, in save
   fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/bird_images/0.png'
```

Any insights would be helpful :)

Comment: The file doesnt exist

Comment: The directory does not exist xD

Comment: To add to the previous tries, I changed the default VS code terminal to cmd from PowerShell and it worked perfectly but when I use the same code in the regular terminal i.e cmd it shows the same errors asked in the question above. Any idea folks?

Comment: and with `set PYTHONPATH=.` before running the command ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to find out what is the issue.

Inside the script, check the value of `dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)`.

The error you encounter seems to be that dirname is the empty string and so the images are trying to get saved in `/bird_images` which does not exist.

It should try to save the images in the local directory `./bird_images/`

You could try :

On Linux :

```
PYTHONPATH=. python bitbird_generation_script.py
```

On Windows:

```
set PYTHONPATH=.
python bitbird_generation_script.py
```

Comment: Somehow now the error has diaspperead but now the error has changed to pillow to                                        from PIL import Image ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'                                                                                                   
The error is related to pil now, but I have verifed that it is installed , The code is still working in the inbulit VS-code terminal.

Comment: I think you have an issue with conda. 
pillow should be installed in your current env. 
Check what env is "activated", `which python` should show the conda one and check pillow is installed.